# function $g$ on $A^*$ by $g(z)=\overline{f\left (\overline z\right )}$. Find $g'(\overline z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $A^*=\{z|\overline z\in A\}$. Suppose $f$ is analytic on $A$, and define a function $g$ on $A^*$ by $g(z)=\overline{f\left (\overline z\right )}$. Find $g'(\overline z)$.

I've shown that $g(z)$ is analytic, but i don't know how to find $g'(\overline z)$.

Comment: What is $z^*$? Perhaps that you mean $g'(z)$.

Comment: Complex conjugate

Comment: So you use two different notations ($\overline z$ and $z^*$) for the complex conjugate of $z$?

Comment: sorry, now supossed to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ and $g(x+yi)=U(x,y)+V(x,y)i$, then, since $g(z)=\overline{f\left(\overline z\right)}$, you have $U(x,y)=u(x,-y)$ and $V(x,y)=-v(x,-y)$. Then\begin{align}g'(x_0-y_0i)&=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x_0,-y_0)+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x_0,-y_0)\\&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)i\\&=\overline{f'(x_0+y_0i)},\end{align}and so $g'\left(\overline z\right)=\overline{f'(z)}$.

Comment: Not $ \overline{ f ^{'} \left ( z \right ) } $ ?

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake.